# Maximum Elo Rating.

Tags: probability, functions, probability-distributions

I'm trying to implement a variant of the Elo system, for a game I'm working on. 
Giving two players $A$ and $B$ with ratings $R_A$ and $R_B$ respectively, the expectation of $A; E_A$ is given by the formula: $$E_A = \frac{1}{1+10^{\frac{R_B-R_A}{Y}}}\tag{*}$$

The expectation of $B$ is similarly given by: $$E_B = \frac{1}{1+10^{\frac{R_A-R_B}{Y}}}$$

The different possible game outcomes are given scores:
A win is $1.0$, a loss is: $0.0$, and a draw is $0.5$. The actual score of $A$ is $S_A$.

After a match between $A$ and $B$, the new ranking of $A; R'_A$ is given by: 
$$R'_A = R_A + K(S_A - E_A)$$

Question:

> Given a sample with a population size of $n$ in which each player reveives an initial rating of $c$. Assuming that the players actively cooperate, what's the ***maximum*** possible rating that one player can receive?

A simpler question is: Is it possible to increase the rating of all players in the sample? I think the answer is 'No' (since the rating gain of each player is deducted from another player). However if it was 'Yes' then there would be no limit, since by induction it will be possible to prove that if a strategy to increase **all** player's rankings from $c$ to $g \{g: c \lt g\}$ existed, then same strategy could be used to improve all rankings from $a$ to $b$ $\{a,b: g \le a \lt b\}$ and there would be no maximum value.

My system doesn't implement the concept of floors or ceilings. $K$ is constant throughout all rankings.  The maximum possible ranking is trivially $\le n\cdot c$, but I want a better upper bound.
(As @Sil points down below:

> $R'_A+R'_B = R_A+R_B$ (since $S_A+S_B=1$ and $E_A+E_B=1$), so the overall ELO sum should remain the same after match as it was before it. $\tag{**}$

The overall ELO sum in this case being: $n \cdot c$

As for a lower bound for max rankings, I'm thinking of a binary search: $n/2$ people win the first $n$ matches.

Their new rating will be calculated as 
$$R' = R + K(1-0.5)$$
$$R' = R + .5K$$

The set will be reduced to $n/2$, and this will continue till set $= 1$.

The number of matches $m$ played this way wilk be approx $\lg n$.

Max ranking through this method, will be: $$c + \frac{K}{2}\cdot \lg n$$

While that provides a lower bound, thus is one scenario in which I think a binary search is suboptimal in increasing rankings.

I think increasing average ratings, may work, but I'm not sure.

I would appreciate an answer where the maximum rating is given as a function of $K, c \& n$.

I'm currently using $K = \sqrt{Y}$

$(*)$ Most chess Elo algorithms use a value of $Y = 400$

$(**)$ By this argument, it is possible to prove that $\not\exists$ a strategy to increase ratings of all players.

It isalso possible to prove that it is impossible to improve average player rankings. (The average rating will **always** remain $1000$)

Comment: If I am not missing something you have $R'_A+R'_B = R_A+R_B$ (since $S_A+S_B=1$ and $E_A+E_B=1$), so the overall ELO sum should remain the same after match as it was before it.

Comment: Yup. Which is why I said the maximum ELO is trivially $\lt n\cdot c$. $n \cdot c$ being the ELO sum.

Comment: I thought you are asking if overall ELO can increase (the second question), which it can't if the sum remains the same.

Comment: This should prove that $\not\exists$ a strategy to increase the ratings of all players. Didn't think of that.

Comment: For clarification, I wasn't really asking if it was possible to increase all player's ELO, (I didn't believe it). I just didn't think of your proof.

Comment: If the difference between two players is large enough, then the higher player would get no points on defeating the lower player.

Comment: Also at some difference between rankings, the expectation gets approximated to 1 or 0. The ELO is an 'int' figure afterall. I'll probably write a program to simulate 2 players starting with an ELO of one. I'll run a few thousand matches and see (without approximation.

Comment: Then nevermind, although I don't see this limitation anywhere in your question, what is this difference limit? Or do you mean that the number will be just too small/rounded?

Comment: @Sil Nah, it isn't part of my question. I'm just saying how Chess organisations calculate ELO. At $800$ points difference, the Expectation of the stronger player is $1$, so he won't get any points if he wins. My question doesn't approximate, but Expectation gets infinitely close to $1$ as the difference increases. Not sure how small it gets, but it quickly gets smaller than $10^{-100}$ (a difference of $2000$ points for $Y = 400 \& K = 20$

Comment: Why is the maximum ELO trivially < n*c? It's not clear to me that ELO cannot drop so far as to become negative?

Comment: @jschnei ; It ***should*** *NOT* be possie, for any player's ratimg to drop to become negative. The lowest ELO a player can have approx. equal $0$.

Comment: @Tobi Why is it impossible? It looks like all that matters in the update equation is the difference between ratings. So if it is possible to get someone down to an ELO of 400 from 1000, it should be possible to get someone down to an ELO of -100 from 500.

Comment: Because the formula that decides expectation. Of player A if he has a rating of $500$ vs player B if he has a rating if $1500$ will give A an expectation of $0$. If A has an expectation of $0$, then his rating cannot drop any lower.